# C# PowerShell Get-Module

Tags: c#, powershell, console

I am trying to create a "custom" PowerShell shell for some of our Azure work and custom modules we developed.
I want to get the list of modules by executing the following, but the outputCollection is empty and nor does the DataAdded event fire.

What on earth am I missing here?

PS: It is PowerShell 5 and I used the Nuget Package Microsoft.PowerShell.5.ReferenceAssemblies

```
using System;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Threading;
namespace TestShell
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                PowerShellInstance.AddScript("Get-Module");

                PSDataCollection<PSObject> outputCollection = new PSDataCollection<PSObject>();
                outputCollection.DataAdded += outputCollection_DataAdded;
                PowerShellInstance.Streams.Error.DataAdded += Error_DataAdded;
                IAsyncResult result = PowerShellInstance.BeginInvoke<PSObject, PSObject>(null, outputCollection);
                while (result.IsCompleted == false)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for pipeline to finish...");
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Execution has stopped. The pipeline state: " + PowerShellInstance.InvocationStateInfo.State);
                foreach (PSObject outputItem in outputCollection)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(outputItem.BaseObject.ToString());
                }
            }
        }

        static void outputCollection_DataAdded(object sender, DataAddedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Object added to output.");
        }

        static void Error_DataAdded(object sender, DataAddedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An error was written to the Error stream!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am being idiot again today. Replace the two lines of PowerShellInstance.AddScript with just PowerShellInstance.AddScript("Get-Module");

Comment: I updated / edited the question with the correct script

Comment: Thank you @TessellatingHeckler. Addition of the -List Available did the trick and the DataAdded event got fired with the objects.
You can post that as an answer.

Comment: Great! I've posted as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing my comments to an answer:

Adding the `-ListAvailable` parameter seems to work for me:

```
PowerShellInstance.AddScript("Get-Module -ListAvailable");
```

for reasons I don't understand, the `Get-Module` output is empty, even though `$env:PsModulePath` looks right, and `PowerShell -NoProfile` still loads a couple of modules, when run via C# it appears not to load any by default.